# (Java) The return type is int, but I can return a char.Why?

Tags: java, return, return-value, return-type

The return type is int, but I can return a char. Why?

```java
 public class Test{
      public int returnInt(){
        return 'a';
    }
}
```

Comment: int is considered a direct supertype to char, therefore you can implicitly convert a char to an int

Answer (score 1):

It will return the ascii value of the character. There is implicit type casting from char to int.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2

Answer (score 0):

char (and other primitive types) in Java are like int's.
so you can use the char as an int see the example

```
char ch = 'a';
ch++;
ch = ch + 'r';
```

so your function will return the corresponding ASCII for that returned char.

Comment: A `char` is not [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).